# View controller appears underneath the toolbar when shown in a popover

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a `UIPopoverController` which shows a `UIToolbar` and a `UICollectionViewController` with a number of cells. The problem that I'm seeing is that the collection view appears underneath the toolbar.

I've tried to move the collection view controller (by changing its origin) to move it below the toolbar, to no avail.

In the screenshot I've made the toolbar translucent so you can see what I mean.

[image]

I'm using the iOS 6 SDK.

The elements that make up the popover are straight forward. I have a custom `UICollectionViewController` which I create in the `init` of my custom `UIPopoverController` class. Here code from that custom `UIPopoverController` class' `init` -- creating the toolbar which is then added along with the collection view controller (`photosCollectionViewController`):

```
// init for the custom UIPopoverController derived class follows:
-(id)init
{
    photosCollectionViewController = [[MyPhotosCollectionViewController alloc] init];
    self = [super initWithContentViewController:photosCollectionViewController];

    if (self) {
        // I tried taking the contentViewController's frame and moving it down 
        // by adding TOOLBAR_HEIGHT to its y co-ordinate, but it does not work.
        CGRect frame = self.contentViewController.view.frame;

        UIToolbar *viewToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, TOOLBAR_HEIGHT)];
        viewToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelTapped:)];
        UIBarButtonItem *separator = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

        CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(viewToolbar.frame.origin.x, viewToolbar.frame.origin.y, 100, 20);
        UIBarButtonItem *title = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[PANGraphicsHelper labelForToolbar:labelFrame text:@"Photos"]];
        UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addPhotopTapped:)];
        viewToolbar.items = @[ cancelButton, separator, title, separator, addButton];
        [self.contentViewController.view addSubview:viewToolbar];
        _toolbar = viewToolbar;

        // Make the popover large enough to hold the 3x3 collection view and the toolbar above
        self.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height + TOOLBAR_HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `contentViewController`?
If it is a ViewController that contains both toolbar and CollectionView, then you should use it in `initWithContentViewController`. Instead you have used photosCollectionViewController.

The heirarchy should be 
UIPopoverController - > ContentViewController

`ContentViewController` should contain at the top and `photosCollectionViewController`'s frame should be adjusted below the toolbar.

Comment: contentViewController is the property of the UIPopoverController which is being initialised in the `init` code shown in the question.

Comment: So you're saying, add the toolbar to the ContentViewController `photosCollectionViewController` instead of adding it afterwards in the popover controller?

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do was to move the `UICollectionViewController`'s `collectionView` down below the toolbar.

```
    UICollectionView *collectionView = ((UICollectionViewController *) self.contentViewController).collectionView;
    CGRect frame = collectionView.frame;
    collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y + TOOLBAR_HEIGHT, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
```